# create a loop structure with Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I would like to generate a special structure to document some R-Code with Sweave.
There are several Articles (for example Product A to Product C) and always the same subsections (for example Promotion and Sales). The structure of the document should now look like this:

\section{Product A} 
\subsection{Promotion} 
graphic to Promotion Product A 
\subsection{Sales} 
graphic to Sales Product A

\section{Product B} 
\subsection{Promotion} 
graphic to Promotion Product B 
\subsection{Sales} 
graphic to Sales Product B

[...]

Because there are a lot more products I need to solve that with some loops.
I tried sevaral attemps with loops in Sweave and \newcommand and \cat but unfortunately nothing leeds to a success... All graphics are in .pdf-format and are created by R.

Has anybody a suggestion or a hint how I can handle this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to do exactly.  Are you looking for some R code that will output the Sweave text you need (to then copy-paste into an Sweave document), or are you hoping for an executable loop within Sweave itself?

Comment: Actually I try to loop within Sweave itself. I have a bunch of plots that I want to integrate in Sweave without change my code everytime (because the amount of plots is changing). I got it for a structure like this: \section{Promotion} and then all graphics for Product A, B and so on. After that \section{Sales} also for Product A, B and so on. I reached this by \newcommand\sales[4]{  
    \subsection{#4}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]%
    \begin{center}%
      \includegraphics{sales#1}%
      \caption{Sales #4}%
      \label{fig:sales #4}%
    \end{center}%
  \end{figure}%
  \clearpage % 
}

Comment: In the the code section I insert something like  cat("\\sales{",i,"} 
        {",           
        profileWeekdays[1],"}{",
        profileWeekdays[2],"}{",
        artName[i],"}\n",
        sep="")    pdf(paste0("sales",i,".pdf"))   in a for loop. That works fine so far but not for the structure in the text document I want to reach...